File Explorer flag not working in Powershell at all
I am trying to write a simple PowerShell function that will open a new explorer window and set its current path to the path passed to the pwsh function
Looking at the documentation for Explorer, the /e flag is what I need
explorer  /e`, "c:\temp"                # works, new explorer with "c:\temp" opens
explorer  /e`, "c:/temp"                # does not work, new explorer with "documents" opens
explorer  "c:/temp"                     # does not work, new explorer with "documents" opens
explorer  "c:\temp"                     # does not work, new explorer with "documents" opens
explorer  "c:\programme files\"         # does not work, new explorer with "documents" opens
explorer  "c:\programme files"          # works, new explorer with "c:\programme files" opens

In a CMD shell explorer /e, c:/temp works but its equivalent in PowerShell does not work at all explorer /e ', c:/temp (I wrote a single quote mark here for Markdowns issue with "`"). So What gives?
I am on pwsh 7.4
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

explorer /e, c:/temp doesnt work for me in cmd



You don't need /e, - just pass the directory path directly to explorer.exe

Be sure to use \, the Windows-native (directory) path separator in the path you pass; / does not work; if the path contains space and ends in \, append a space before the closing quote (see below).


Therefore:
# Note the use of "\"
explorer.exe c:\temp

# Note the use of a trailing space if the path ends in "\"
# (only needed in PowerShell 7)
explorer.exe 'c:\program files\ '

As for ending a path in \:

explorer.exe "c:\program files\" - as well as the equivalent explorer.exe 'c:\program files\' - works fine in Windows PowerShell, but not in PowerShell (Core) 7.[1]

A workaround that works in both editions is to append a space: explorer.exe "c:\program files\ "


As for needing to escape , as `,:

This is only required in Windows PowerShell, and only if the folder path is specified as a separate argument - and this requirement is arguably a bug.

Generally, both PowerShell editions pass an unquoted , through as-is when calling external programs (whereas an unquoted , in calls to PowerShell commands is a metacharacter that constructs arrays).

PowerShell 7 does so consistently, whereas Windows PowerShell mistakenly removes an instance of ,  if it occurs at the end of an argument.
For instance, explorer /e, c:\temp works fine in PowerShell 7, but requires explorer /e`, c:\temp in Windows PowerShell, whereas explorer /e,c:\temp works fine in both editions, because the , is argument-internal..




[1] The reason is that Windows PowerShell passes "c:\program files\" as-is on the process command line that used to invoke explorer.exe, even though this argument form is arguably broken, given that \" should be considered an escaped " char. rather than a literal \ followed by a closing ". PowerShell 7 fixes this problem, and now passes "c:\program files\\" behind the scenes, following Microsoft's parsing rules for C/C++ command-line applications.  However, explorer.exe seemingly requires the broken form to work correctly.

This exaplains a lot, I understand better in what I was dealing with now. Cheers!

Glad to hear it, @Ralf_Reddings; my pleasure.
